# LDAP - cannot enable user using spring java ldap api

Tags: active-directory, spring-ldap

Trying to enable user account and getting below error. If I go to directly to that windows machine after creating user (using java api)  and update password (manually using UI on windows machine) like "password1" and then try to enable password using java it works fine.

Here is how I am setting password while creating user

```
BasicAttribute basicAttribute1=new BasicAttribute("userPassword","password1".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
            context.setAttribute(basicAttribute1);
```

Then trying to change useraccount control to 512 and getting

```
 "errorMessage": "[LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n\u0000]; nested exception is javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n\u0000]; remaining name 'CN=SachinVTendulkar,OU=SDCWASD001,OU=Users,OU=Mycity,OU=Enterprise Support'"
```

Seems I am not setting password correctly while creating user with java - I am creating user with userAccountControl-514 and with password along with other attributes like names etc (first I want to create in disable mode)

Then when I just try to enable user, getting this problem. And for same user if I go to windows machine and update password and then try to enable with java it works fine - so that rule out other issues like ldaps etc.

Logs when I create user for reference:

log of creating user : creating new user : JohnSmith , in DN : CN=JohnSmith,OU=SDCWASD001,OU=Users,OU=MyCity,OU=Enterprise Support , with context: org.springf.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter: dn=CN=JohnSmith,OU=SDCWASD001,OU=Users,OU=MyCity,OU=Enterprise Support {mail=adsadsa51@test.com, Description=Test account, CN=JohnSmith,  objectclass[0]=top, objectclass[1]=Person, objectclass[2]=organizationalPerson, objectclass[3]=user, userPassword=summer01, sAMAccountName=adsadsa51, userPrincipalName=adsadsa51@test.com, givenName=John, displayName=JohnSmith, name=JOHNSMITH, physicalDeliveryOfficeName=0, sn=Smith, userAccountControl=514}

Then to enable user, I do following and getting that error (I do this in seperate call)

```
ModificationItem[] mods=new ModificationItem[1];
         mods[0]=new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl",Integer.toString(512)));
 ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn, mods);
```

Comment: Why do you have a semi-colon at `US_ASCII);`; remove that.

Comment: Please include the actual exception generating code.

Comment: org.springframework.ldap.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution is to use SSL for password attribute updates.

Can you be more specific about what this entails?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [unicodePwd value on the account](https://nawilson.com/2010/08/26/ldap-password-changes-in-active-directory/). Something like:

```
final byte[] quotedPasswordBytes = ('"'+password+'"').getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    container.put(new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", quotedPasswordBytes));
```

Comment: in that case it gives this error while creating user:[LDAP: error code 53 - 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n\u0000]; nested exception is javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n\u0000];